# Curl requiring ciphers to be specified

Tags: openssl, curl

I am trying to run this command:

```
curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

On my ubuntu machine, it failes with the following error:

```
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

However, I also use an amazon ec2 instance, which I believe is based on CentOS, where it works. I have discovered that if I run this command instead:

```
curl --cipher DEFAULT https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

Then it works, I can run it on ubuntu, but not on amazon! It is complaining that DEFAULT is not a valid list. In fact, I can't find any ciphers that work on amazon at all - something to do with it using NSS instead of whatever ubuntu has?

This has only been a problem since yesterday, when I did an apt-get upgrade, which must have broken something. What do I need to do to get curl working normally again?

My Ubuntu version is 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Some sites disable support for SSL 3.0 (possible because of many exploits/vulnerabilities), so it's possible to force specific SSL version by either `-2`/`--sslv2` or `-3`/`--sslv3`.
Also `-L` is worth a try if requested page has moved to a different location.

In my case it was a `curl` bug, so `curl` needs to be upgraded to the latest version (>7.40) and it worked fine.

See also:

- [3 Common Causes of Unknown SSL Protocol Errors with cURL](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html)
- [Error when Installing Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679961/error-when-installing-meteor-in-ubuntu) at SO
- [[Bug 861137] Re: Openssl TLS errors while connecting to SSLv3 sites](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2013-July/155861.html)
- [How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) at Unix SE